# Multiple apps sharing same reference data . .

Tags: c#, winforms, memory

I have multiple winforms applications that download large sets of reference data on startup.  I realized that there might be a more efficient way to store this data locally instead of duplicating the memory in everyone one of the applications.  This data is used for large drop down pick lists and data mappings.  Does anyone have an out of process memory map solution or something that would allow this to avoid the duplication and reduce memory overhead in each applications.

Comment: How much data is it? 1 megabyte? 1 gigabyte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you can use Microsoft Enterprise SSO to store configuration data (this might be an overkill). the data will be accessible through SSO API. 
   [SSO Configuration Store](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2007/09/21/biztalk-sso-configuration-data-storage-tool/)
2. make a windows service to cache data for you and you can access data through IPC
3. can use .Net remoting to access data across applications